# How to get the compressed file name in Drupal?

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7

After compressing the JS file in Drupal I got a randomly JS file name.

**My question how I can get this file name to add it to my javascript?**

**Drupal code:** import and compress

```
<?php drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . 'mybigfile.js'); ?>
```

**Random file name Result:**

```
js_2KQpJNjjupC1Beoweoqpok2JCXhe0sJ6YBllaRDUXYQ.js
```

**Trying to Call the mybigfile.js file:**

```
<script>
telInput.intlTelInput({
      validationScript: "mybigfile.js"
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can not get the name of the concatenated JavaScript file generated by Drupal using PHP.

Your best option would be to avoid your JavaScript file `mybigfile.js` from being concatenated and compressed. Then you can apply your validation script by calling the file name.

You will have to set the `preprocess` property to `false` inside [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) `$options` array, to prevent the file from being aggregated.

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/mybigfile.js', array(
    'type'      => 'file',
    'preprocess'=> false,
));
```

---

### Update

If you want to compress a single JavaScript file, you have the option to use [AdvAgg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) API.

Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation for how to do that. But you start with the following:

1. download and install `advagg` and enable the submodule `advagg_js_compress`.
2. inside the `advagg_js_compress` submodule folder, find the file `advagg_js_compress.advagg.inc` and open in your text editor. Here you can find a few helper functions that will help you compressing your JavaScript file.

Comment: My goal is to get the compressed version some how.. other ways your solution it will work perfectly.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it could be helpful this time :)